# Error encountered while running a PS command to reduce the size of WinSxS folder in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell

I am trying to reduce the size of winSxS by removing some features via windows [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell). However, I used the following command but it is returning an error message:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object -FilterScript {$.Installed -Eq $FALSE} | Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Remove
The term 'Uninstall-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:101 + Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object -FilterScript {$.Installed -Eq $FALSE} | Uninstall-WindowsFeature <<<<   -Remove
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Uninstall-WindowsFeature:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to solve it by importing module using this command but didn't work: 
`Import-Module ServerManager`

Then tried to run the first command above again but failed with the same error.

Any ideas?
I have asked in SuperUser community but no one has answered yet. Seems that stackoverflow has more active users than SuperUser.   Hence, I am asking here due to the time constraint I have.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the proper cmdlet for before 2012 is `Remove-WindowsFeature`. You could easily figure this out with `Get-Command *feature*`. Take a loot at this [article](https://serverfault.com/questions/650613/whats-the-difference-between-remove-windowsfeature-and-uninstall-windowsfeature).